# Error occurs when batch file is already an .exe file

Tags: batch-file

My colleague created a batch file, when we run it as a batch file it works fine
but when we run it as an .exe file an error occurs.

We converted the batch file into an .exe file using IEXPRESS

The error that shows up is "Out of environment space switch - /q"

(i think the error occurs in the part of deleting temporary files)

any help or assistance will be highly appreciated

```
@echo off

c:\

ipconfig /flushdns

nbtstat -r

nbtstat -R

nbtstat -c

net start 

gpupdate /force

rem cd %userprofile%\appdata\local\temp
set Tempfile=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\TEMP
del /q /s /f "%Tempfile%"
rem del C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\TEMP /Q

rem Delete Temporary Internet Files
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8

rem Delete Cookies
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2

rem Delete History
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1

rem Delete Form Data
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16

rem Delete Passwords
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32

rem Delete All
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

rem Delete All – “Also delete files and settings stored by add-ons”
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351

set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Intern~1

del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rem rd /s /q "%DataDir%"

set History=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History

del /q /s /f "%History%"
rem rd /s /q "%History%"

set IETemp=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Tempor~1

del /q /s /f "%IETemp%"
rem rd /s /q "%IETemp%"

set Cookies=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies

del /q /s /f "%Cookies%"
rem rd /s /q "%Cookies%"

rem C:\bin\regdelete.exe HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"
```

Comment: Searching Google for the phrase "Out of environment switch" returns only two results, one of which is this question. Are you sure that's the exact error message? Also, is there any particular reason the task needs to be an executable?

Comment: Yes that's the error when i used IEXPRESS, but in other bat to exe converters it doesn't show that error but the execution stops after the gpupdate...actually we can do it manually..but the reason we want it to be executable is for the ease of our end users because we work in tech support and we just want to save time for the users especially if that is the common issue specifically issues regarding Oracle ERP System

Comment: c:\ is not a command. Use cd /D C:\ if you want to change working directory to root of drive `C:`.

Comment: update:  sorry i made a typo, here is the complete error message
"Out of environment space switch - /q"

Comment: Avoid making your batch file depending on list of directories in environment variable __PATH__ and list of file extensions in environment variable __PATHEXT__. Use everywhere `%SystemRoot%\System32\command.exe` except for internal commands of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Instead of `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` use `%USERPROFILE%`. And better use `set "DataDir=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Intern~1"` and `set "History=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History"`.

Comment: The string assigned to `Tempfile` is the directory referenced also by environment variable __TEMP__. It is not possible to delete a directory with command `del`. Are you sure this batch file runs without any error as .bat file. I don't think so. Append command `pause` at end or run this batch file manually from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on it to see all the errors output.

Comment: "Out of environment space" is an error message indicating that memory reserved for environment variables is too low for all the environment variables created during execution of a batch file. I do not see any real reason for creating new environment variables at all in this batch file as it should only cleanup some directories by deleting all files and subdirectories in those directories.

Comment: Yes i guess so, well it's not really necessary, we can do it manually anyways...but thanks for the help

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/261825. It only applies to the legacy command.com shell, but relevant here. A workaround when using cmd.exe is to set a large environment variable (just type a long string) on the target machine, forcing it to increase the available space, then delete its value in your script (`SET MYVAR=`) to use that space.